# Mybatis: How to pass an array of objects to stored procedure?

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis

I have created a `MyObjectArrayTypeHandler` class which implements `TypeHandler<MyObject[]>`. I am not able to figure out how to override `setParameter()` and `getResult()` methods?
There are couple of examples available to do it for `Oracle` database but there is no example for `Postgres` database.
Any help with regards with respect to `Postgres` database will be very useful.

Comment: What is `TypeHandler<T>` and what library is it from?

Comment: @SamTebbs33 MyHabits.